# Magento2 Send invoice programatically

Tags: magento2.2, email, invoice

I have store with de_DE localization.
I created new mass action for send invoice emails. It works. This is my code:

```
    protected function massAction(AbstractCollection $collection)
{
    $countSendInvoice = 0;

    foreach ($collection->getItems() as $order) {
        if (!$order->getEntityId()) {
            continue;
        }
        $dataOrder = $this->modelOrder->load($order->getEntityId());
        $invoiceCollection = $dataOrder->getInvoiceCollection();
        if($invoiceCollection->count()) {
            foreach ($invoiceCollection as $invoice) {
                if ($invoice->getState() == \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice::STATE_PAID) {
                    $this->notifyInvoice->send($invoice, true);
                    $countSendInvoice++;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    if ($countSendInvoice) {
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You have sended %1 invoice(s).', $countSendInvoice));
    } else {
        $this->messageManager->addError(__('No invoice(s) were sended.'));
    }

    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $resultRedirect->setPath($this->getComponentRefererUrl());
    return $resultRedirect;
}
```

But i received email only on en_US localization. When I send by standart methods from view invoice page it sended on de_DE.
How can I send invoice programmatically with right localization?

Comment: can u please share notifyInvoice->send() function code?

Comment: have you created email template per localization?

Comment: @Abdul I've added localization for store de_DE
And when i send invoice from admin panel, it is on de_DE.

Comment: $notifyInvoice->send() is standart magento function